# Custom Report Type lookup field not showing in report builder

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I have set up a custom report type with Opportunities which can have 1 or many assets:

[image]

On the Opportunity object exists an Invoice object and in the layout properties, I've created a look up field from Opportunity > Invoice to get the invoice name:

[image]

I've also enabled "Checked by Default":

[image]

But this field is not showing in my report builder when I use this custom report type. Any ideas why?

Comment: A) your report type is for opps with 1 or more assets, not 0 or more.  0 or more would be opps with or without assets.  B) re field not showing make sure you have access to the field in opp and the invoice object itself.

Comment: @gorav thanks, I'm pretty sure I have access to both the field and object as I'm the admin.

Comment: Admin access does not come with field level security or access to an object, it does have to be granted via profile or perm set.  If you can view the data in the ui, or in another report, then it's safe to say you have access.  Being an admin does give a lot of power but object level access and field level access still is required to be set.

Comment: I also have the same problem.
I add to custom report of activities fields via lookup from cases. I can see those fields in the standard report of cases and can’t see them in the relevant report builder .